# Using `transform` to create an increasing vector

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I am trying to make an increasing vector using `transform` and must not be doing it correctly. I want to use transform. What am I doing wrong?

PS - I will be using the c++ 11 standard and g++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> x(10);
    x.front() = 0.0;
    double h = 0.1;
    std::transform(x.begin(), x.end() - 1, x.begin() + 1, [h](unsigned int xn) {return xn + h;});
    std::cout << x.at(3) << " " << x.at(9) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `[h](unsigned int xn)` -> `[h](double xn)`

Comment: Do you want to you want to change the items ? Or do you want to append additional transformed items ? Or do you just want to populate a vector with an arithmetic sequence ?

Comment: This looks like a job for `std::generate`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want to do. Maybe you want to have a look at [back_inserter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter).

Answer (score 5):

The conversion to unsigned int is truncating each value when it is used to calculate the next

Comment: That's one reason why one should always use `auto` when writing a lambda for a function :)

Comment: @Rakete1111: That's only supported since C++14, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

## [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) - Using an unary operator

> `std::transform` applies the given function to a range and stores the
>   result in another range, beginning at d_first.

Via `std::transform` and a closure you can initialize your `std::vector`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<double> v(10);
  const double step = 0.1;

  std::transform(begin(v), end(v), begin(v),
                 [step](const double value) { return value + step; });

  for (const auto value : v) {
    std::cout << value << ' ';
  }
}
```

## [`std::generate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) - Increment via a callable

> Assigns each element in range [first, last) a value generated by the
>   given function object

If you want a custom increment, you can use [`std::generate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<double> v(10);
  double seed = 0.0;

  std::generate(begin(v), end(v), [&seed]() {
    const auto ret = seed;
    seed += 0.1;
    return ret;
  });

  for (const auto value : v) {
    std::cout << value << ' ';
  } // outputs: 0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 
}
```

## [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) - Increment via `++value`

*Slightly off topic. You can provide a type with a `operator++` for an increment of `0.1` but it is not intuitive for the reader.*

You can use [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) which relies on `operator++`.

> Fills the range [first, last) with sequentially increasing values, starting with value and repetitively evaluating `++value`.

The code in your case will be:

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<double> v(10);

  std::iota(begin(v), end(v), 0.0);

  for (const auto value : v) {
    std::cout << value << ' ';
  } // outputs: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
}
```

Comment: Did not know about `iota`. Very useful.

Comment: this does not result in the required output - he wants to increment by 0.1. You need to make the 3rd argument of std::iota a custom object that supports `operator++` and `operator double`.

Answer (score 1):

The lambda declares a wrong type of the parameter

```
[h](unsigned int xn) {return xn + h;});
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

There should be

```
[h]( double xn ) {return xn + h;});
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other ways to write this. You may find them more expressive.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

std::vector<double> create1(double i, double h)
{
  std::vector<double> v(10);
  std::generate(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 
                [&]() mutable
  {
    auto result = i;
    i += h;
    return i;
  });
  return v;
}

std::vector<double> create2(double i, double h)
{
  std::vector<double> v(10);
  for (std::size_t x = 0 ; v.size() ; ++x) {
    v[x] = i + h * x; 
  }
  return v;
}

std::vector<double> create3(double i, double h)
{
  struct emitter
  {
    emitter& operator++() {
      i += h;
    }
    operator double() const { return i; }
    double i, h;
  };
  std::vector<double> v(10);
  std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), emitter { i, h });
  return v;
}

int main()
{
  auto v1 = create1(0, 0.1);
  auto v2 = create2(0, 0.1);
  auto v3 = create3(0, 0.1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of any other problems it might have, your implementation has a subtle flaw: it relies on each preceding value in the vector having been already set.

This is not guaranteed to work, because [std::transform()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) [does not guarantee in-order application of the operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform#Notes).